# Unity Editor hangs on play but build works fine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue with the Unity editor. My project has been working fine and I hadn't touched it in a while and didn't change any Unity options. Now when I start it, it hangs on play or when I try to close the editor. If I make a build instead, it works as intended.

This project was initially on version 2019.1.9. I have tried it on newer versions to see if it would make a difference. The problem persists on newer versions. There is nothing printed on console, and editor logs don't seem to provide any useful information other than the ordinary. I have tried going back to a working backup version and slowly introduced new elements. It stopped working at some point in a very simple FPS counter file. When I removed said code, the problem persisted. I don't know if it is related but there also seems to be some licensing issues, I am using Pro and I can use some of its feature and it says my license is active, but for some reason my builds have "educational use only" watermark.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: Maybe also try to clean your project folder (usually you can remove anything except `Assets` and `ProjectSettings` ... especially delete the `Library` folder Unity will then recreate it and maybe loose some old artefacts from this FPS counter thing. **Backup first** ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning everything in the folder except assets  as per derHugo's advice worked.